# Tensorflow served model fails with error : "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor "

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Following is the `signature def` of the tensorflow model being served:

MetaGraphDef with `tag-set: 'serve'` contains the following:

```
SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['in'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 10)
        name: input_sentences:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['out'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: output_sentences:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

After serving this model, when I pass an input of shape `[-1, 10]`, I get the following error:

```
"You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'output_sentences' with dtype int32 and shape [?,1]"
```

even though `output_sentences` is part of outputs.

Please help me out.

Comment: Hi. It seems that you are trying to pass an input which is not compatible with the shaped mentioned in the placeholder. The shape of the placeholder is [?,1] and you are trying to pass [-1,10]

Comment: @nidhi-d did you end up solving this problem? I'm facing the same issue and my input tensor is the correct shape/dtype...